# How does the message queue work in Win32?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-messages

I read some stuff on Win32 and how the message loop works, and there's something that is still unclear to me: What exactly is stored in the message queue? The integer value that corresponds to a message (`WM_COMMAND`, `WM_CREATE`, etc) or a pointer to a `MSG` structure containing the message integer value and other stuff like `wParam`, `lParam`, etc?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer your question narrowly, each message in the queue stores, at the least,

- a window handle to which the message is directed,
- the message code, wParam and lParam, as you already correctly noted,
- the time when the message was posted, that you retrieve with `GetMessageTime()`,
- for UI messages, the position of the cursor when the message was *posted* (see `GetMessagePos()`).

Note that not all messages are actually stored in the queue. Messages that are sent with `SendMessage()` to a window from the thread that owns the window are never stored; instead, a receiver window's message function is called directly. Messages sent from other threads are stored until processed, and the sending thread blocks until the message is replied to, either by exiting the window function or explicitly with a call to `ReplyMessage()`. The API function `InSendMessage()` helps figure out whether the windows function is processing a message sent from another thread.

Messages that you or the system post are stored in the queue, with some exceptions.

- WM_TIMER messages are never actually *stored*; instead, `GetMessage()` constructs a timer message if there are no other messages in the queue and a timer has matured. This means that, first, the timer messages have the lowest dequeuing priority, and, second, that multiple messages from a short period timer would never overflow queue, even if `GetMessage()` is not called for a while. As a result, a *single* WM_TIMER message is sent for the given timer, even if the timer has elapsed multiple times since the last WM_TIMER message from that timer has been processed.
- Similarly, WM_QUIT is also not stored, and rather only flagged. `GetMessage()` pretends to have retrieved the WM_QUIT after the queue has been exhausted, and this is the last message it retrieves.
- Another example is the WM_PAINT message (hat tip to @cody-gray for reminding about this). This message is also simulated when any part of the window¹ is marked as "dirty" and needs repainting. This is also a low-priority message, made so that multiple invalidated regions in a window are repainted all at once when the queue becomes empty, to reduce responsiveness of the GUI and reduce flicker. You can force an immediate repaint by calling `UpdateWindow()`. This function acts like `SendMessage()`, in the sense that it does not return until the exposed part of the window is redrawn. This function does *not* send a WM_PAINT to the window if the invalid region of that window is empty, as an obvious optimization.

Probably, there are other exceptions and internal optimizations.

Messages posted with `PostMessage()` end up in the queue of a thread that owns the window to which the message is posted.

In what form the messages are stored internally, we do not know, and we do not care. Windows API abstracts that completely. The MSG structure is filled in memory you pass to `GetMessage()` or `PeekMessage()`. You do not need to know or to worry about the details of internal implementation beyond those documented in Windows SDK guides.

---

¹ I do not know how exactly WM_PAINT and WM_TIMER are prioritized relative to each other. I assume WM_PAINT has a lower priority, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I see. So what if a message is sent with SendMessage() when another message (sent by SendMessage()) is already being processed/handled? What happens then since it's not stored anywhere?

Comment: Consider a single thread. The thread is "processing a message" if and only if it has entered a message function (by way of SendMessage()), and the function has not yet returned. If you call SendMessage() from inside the message function, then another message function is called (or the same one indeed is called recursively), immediately, on the same call stack. After it has processed the message, control returns from SendMessage(). You can think of SendMessage() as a way to *call* message function, only that it does additional fancy dispatching based on hWnd.

Comment: Like `WM_TIMER`, `WM_PAINT` is another exception, a message that is never actually "stored" in the queue. Of course, the real answer to the question comes in the last paragraph: all of this is implementation detail and it is quite irrelevant to the programmer. He or she should only be concerned with what is documented in the SDK, not relying on implementation details subject to change with any release.

Comment: I do want to know and worry about the details of internal implementation beyond those documented in Windows SDK guides. This answer is very bad one. DO NOT assume what other people want of don't want to know.

Answer (score 9):

The message queue in Windows is an *abstraction*.  Very helpful to think of it as a queue but the actual implementation of it is far more detailed.  There are four distinct sources of messages in Windows:

- Messages that are delivered by SendMessage(). Windows directly calls the window procedure, the message isn't returned by Peek/GetMessage() but does require a call to that function to get dispatched.  By far the most messages are delivered this way.  WM_COMMAND is like that, it is directly sent by the code that translates a key-down event, like TranslateAccelerator().  No queue-like behavior.
- Messages that are synthesized from the window state.  Best examples are WM_PAINT, delivered when the "window has a dirty rectangle" state flag is set.  And WM_TIMER, delivered when the "timer has expired" state flag is set.  These are 'low priority' messages, only delivered when the message queue is empty.  They are delivered by GetMessage() but do not otherwise live on the queue.
- Input event messages for the keyboard and mouse.  These are the messages that truly have queue-like behavior.  For the keyboard this ensures that type-ahead works, no keystroke gets lost when the program isn't ready to accept a keystroke.  A bunch of state is associated with it, the entire state of the keyboard gets copied for example.  Roughly the same for the mouse except that there's less state.  The WM_MOUSEMOVE message is an interesting corner case, the queue does *not* store every single pixel traversed by the cursor.  Position changes are accumulated into a single message, stored or delivered when necessary.
- Messages stored in the queue by an explicit PostMessage() call.  That's entirely up to the program code, clearly it only needs to store the arguments of the call plus the time the call was made so it can accurately be replayed back at GetMessage() time.

Comment: "Windows directly calls the window procedure, the message isn't returned by Peek/GetMessage() but does require a call to that function to get dispatched."  The dispatching bit is only true for cross-thread messages?  Otherwise it's just a function call.

Comment: _"Windows directly calls the window procedure, the message isn't returned by Peek/GetMessage() but does require a call to that function to get dispatched"_ But why? I can't fathom why in the world you need `GetMessage()` to dispatch `SendMessage()` if it calls `WindowProc` directly???

Comment: The OS cannot arbitrarily interrupt a program from what it is doing by the time somebody calls SendMessage.  That would cause horrible [re-entrancy bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)).  It has to be idle, expecting to receive a message and process it.  GetMessage() tells the OS that the program is in that safe state.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has a nice article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explaining everything on messages and message queues.

But to answer your question, the Queue exists for each window, it temporarily stores the messages and their associate parameters, whether of not its a queue of `MSG`'s is implementation defined, but it most likely is (or something similar). It should also be noted that not all messages will go to the queue, some require immediate processing.

Comment: With all due respect, the statement about a queue per window is incorrect. Queues are created per thread, or can be shared by more than one thread by way of `::AttachThreadInput()`. See Nancy's old but good article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810439.aspx